# How to create a Python AWS Lambda zip with OpenCV + FFmpeg?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

On my desktop I have FFmpeg, OpenCV compilated right, and works well.

The function **load a video** on S3 and run a model that **extract some frames** and store them in another **S3 Bucket**.

But I have to deploy a conda env with my **lambda function** and packages with **OpenCV** without **FFmpeg**, but I need it to opencv mp4 video file.

```
python-project/
    - cv2/
    - numpy/
    - lambda_handler.py
```

How can I setup the opencv that enable videos on OpenCV? I tried to compile in another desktop but none.

Comment: It sounds like `elastictranscoder` might be fit for your requirements?

Comment: Thanks @Henry for your reply, but what I have to do is extract some features frames based in a model, `elastictranscoder` works only for transcoder =(